# SQL Query condensing

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two very similar SQL queries that return a count of minutes spent on a different work area.

Is it possible to condense them into one query?

Parameters needed:

Show the current month (IE 1 for Jan, 4 for April)
Show the total minutes count from both queries into one single query.

Here are the queries I have at the moment:

```
SELECT SUM(r.Minutes_Spent) AS 'Custom Programming and Consulting'
FROM TK_Project p
INNER JOIN TK_Task t
ON p.Project_ID = t.Project_ID JOIN TK_Time_Record r
ON t.ID = r.Task_ID
WHERE p.Company = 162
AND p.Name ='Technical Support'
AND r.Work_Date BETWEEN  '04/01/2001'  AND  '04/30/2012'
AND r.Type NOT LIKE '%non%'
AND (r.Type = 'Programming-Billable' OR r.Type = 'Consulting-Billable')

SELECT SUM(r.Minutes_Spent) AS 'Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training'
FROM TK_Project p
INNER JOIN TK_Task t
ON p.Project_ID = t.Project_ID JOIN TK_Time_Record r
ON t.ID = r.Task_ID
WHERE p.Company = 162
AND p.Name ='Technical Support'
AND r.Work_Date BETWEEN  '04/01/2001'  AND  '04/30/2012'
AND r.Type NOT LIKE '%non%'
AND (r.Type = 'Data Maintenance' OR r.Type = 'Tech Support-Billable' OR r.Type = 'Training')
```

Here is the data they provide:

```
Custom Programming and Consulting
90

Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training
105
```

Is it possible to get the above queries pushed into one query and it return the following data:

```
Month      Custom Programming and Consulting      Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training
  4                    90                                           105
```

The month would need to show the current month that is in this part of the query:

```
AND r.Work_Date BETWEEN  '04/01/2001'  AND  '04/30/2012'
```

I'm not sure the best way to achieve this. I need the month because the next part I will need to upgrade this to is to go back 12 months from todays date for a graphical bar chart report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes . . . you simply need case statements in the SELECT clause to group the values the way you need them:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(case 
        when r.Type in ('Programming-Billable', 'Consulting-Billable')
        then r.Minutes_Spent
        end) AS "Custom Programming and Consulting",
  SUM(case 
        when (r.Type in ('Data Maintenance', 'Tech Support-Billable', 'Training')
        then r.Minutes_Spent
        end) AS "Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training"
FROM TK_Project p 
INNER JOIN TK_Task t
  ON p.Project_ID = t.Project_ID 
JOIN TK_Time_Record r
  ON t.ID = r.Task_ID
WHERE p.Company = 162 
  AND p.Name ='Technical Support' 
  AND r.Work_Date BETWEEN  '04/01/2001'  AND  '04/30/2012' 
  AND r.Type NOT LIKE '%non%'
```